# HTML editor losses value in button submit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fckeditor, html-editor

Value Loss in my HTML editor and fileupload ctrl

This is my sample code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_pnl_Ctrls" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        // TextBox ctrls and Radio buttons
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_pnl_Send_Key" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    //File Upload Ctrl
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCreate"></asp:PostBackTrigger>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" EnableViewState="true" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlMailContent" runat="server">
                    <FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor ID="FCKeditor1" runat="server" BasePath="~/FCKEditor/" ImageBrowserURL="~/FCKEditor/"
                        LinkBrowserURL="~/FCKEditor/" Height="630px" Width="890px">
                    </FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor>
                    <div class="input-field-error-container">
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
<div class="button-text-2">
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCreate" runat="server" ValidationGroup="PublishUser" OnClick="btnCreate_Click"
                CausesValidation="true">Publish</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

If i do with Fileupload and i entered a text in HTML Editor when i submits; Fileupload.hasfile fails also entered values in editor could not get back at the serverend

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set that upPnl UpdateMode="Conditional" then i got it perfectly...
but really sad no answers and even comments :(